# Navigation between two modules in Android

Tags: android, navigation

I have two modules in application A and B,

In module A I have declared a dependency on module B like,

A's build.gradle

```
    implementation customModulePath(':B')
```

Now From A, I can navigate to some screens in module B, but for some business logic
I have to navigate from B to A module on some dependency.

When I have added Module A dependency in Module B like,

```
implementation customModulePath(':A')
```

I am getting a circular dependency error.

So, How can achieve navigation between these two modules like,

1. A -> B
2. B -> A

Answer (score 0):

IMO, You've to modularize components according to their nature. For eg.

- `UI` : All UI related things should come under this module. Like `Activities, Fragment, Dialogs etc`
- `Domain` : All business logic should come under this module
- `Data` : All data related things should come under this module.

Also, you should consider your project size in order to follow such a pattern. If it's a small app, there's no need to follow a modularized project structure like this. Please take a look at [the Clean Architecture Pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=Clean%20Architecuture%20Android%20MVVM)